# Is there anyway to get firebase to reissue an SSL cert?

Tags: firebase, ssl, firebase-hosting

I have a custom domain setup for a site hosted on Firebase. HTTPS as working fine on the firebase project domain and the custom domain but recently it has stopped working on the custom domain.

When I attempt to load the site in chrome I get this error:
`ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

Chrome wont even let me continue. Any help would be appreciated.

The domain is https://sitepack.co.nz if that helps

Comment: This is more question for serverfault.com. Did you check https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain?

Comment: There's no public API for this. You might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.